# PHP: Fatal error

Tags: php, memory

I happen to run a php script and i encountered the following error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1820327936) (tried to allocate 33554432 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\interim3\Includes\Controller\db_querystatements.php on line 84
```

in my db_querystatements.php i have set the memory limit to unlimited `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

the error point to the following codes:

```
function dbQueryAclLocalPort(){
$db_data = new PDO ('sqlite:././Database/information.sqlite');
$result_data = $db_data->query('SELECT local_port from attacked_acl');

    foreach ($result_data as $row_data)
    {
    $acllocalport[] = $row_data['local_port'];
    }

    return $acllocalport;
}

function dbQueryAclLocalHost(){
$db_data = new PDO ('sqlite:././Database/information.sqlite');
$result_data = $db_data->query('SELECT local_host from attacked_acl');

    foreach ($result_data as $row_data)
    {
    $acllocalhost[] = $row_data['local_host'];
    }

    return $acllocalhost;
}
```

any advise? thanks

Comment: This means you've somehow triggered a memory leak. Please include the code from your affected scripts so we can point out to you what's causing the problem.

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with?

Comment: quite a lot. probably over 100+

Comment: over 100 is not quite a lot. unless you'r storing full length movies in your database

Comment: actually to be exact is over 4000 over pages of results. each of this result shows over 20 rows and 6-7 columns

Comment: perhaps (I could be wrong), but your initiating a new pdo object every-time you invoke thos functions without closing the pdo once your done. you may want to try a singleton approach and just pass the connection as a parameter...

Comment: hmm yes. i have PDO open for each column in the database amounting to over 5 PDO's. should i null them instead after each call? thanks!

Comment: i have closed the connection after each call but was unable to solve the problem still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems to be using 1.8 GB of memory. It seems to be hitting the *system's* physical limit.

Try to reduce your script's memory usage or fix the memory leak that is causing this.